# I got error from the curl when testing riak

Tags: riak

I'm newbie to Riak and web service

I follow the [riak fast track](http://wiki.basho.com/The-Riak-Fast-Track.html),In server side I type

`riak start`

and in a client side, I run `curl -H "Accept: text/plain" http://markson.hk:8093/stats`

I got an error:

`curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

update

on the server side it actually works:

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8098/ping

response: OK
```

But on my client machine

curl -v http://116.255.139.151:8098/ping

it doesn't work and returns:

```
bogon:~ yozloy$ curl -v http://116.255.139.151:8098/ping
* About to connect() to 116.255.139.151 port 8098 (#0)
*   Trying 116.255.139.151... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

And Nginx welcome pages works!

Comment: Have you checked any and all firewalls between client and server, and if you are in control of their settings, have you verified that they're correct? I can tell you that I get "OK" when I try http://116.255.139.151:8098/ping,  and I am in the U.S. using an iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a network issue, you can try a proxy or a remote VPS server

```
ping 116.255.139.151
PING 116.255.139.151 (116.255.139.151) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 116.255.139.151: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=222 ms
64 bytes from 116.255.139.151: icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=223 ms
```

And I run that on the server same command you are using, I got correct result.

```
 curl -v http://116.255.139.151:8098/ping
* About to connect() to 116.255.139.151 port 8098 (#0)
*   Trying 116.255.139.151... connected
* Connected to 116.255.139.151 (116.255.139.151) port 8098 (#0)
> GET /ping HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.5 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15
> Host: 116.255.139.151:8098
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.9.0 (participate in the frantic)
< Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2011 07:00:46 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 2
< 
* Connection #0 to host 116.255.139.151 left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Hope that is useful for your troubleshooting.

Comment: I corrected the configure file of riak, now everything works like charm!

Comment: I'm having this same issue. What exactly did you do?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem setting up riak 1.4.2 in a virtual machine and then trying to access the API from the host machine via port forwarding.

The solution was to edit the riak [app.config](http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.4.2/ops/advanced/configs/configuration-files/) file and change the `http` setting.
The default/initial setting was:

```
{http, [ {"127.0.0.1", 8098} ]}
```

...which only binds to the loopback interface.  If you want riak to respond on other interfaces you have to add them to the setting like:

```
{http, [ {"X.X.X.X", 8098}, {"127.0.0.1", 8098} ]}
```

where `X.X.X.X` is the address bound to the other interface you would like to use.
In the case of my VM this was a 10.0.X.X address.

There is also a similarly formatted `pb` setting for the protocol buffers API which you may want to update as well if you want to access the server using the protocol buffers API from a client machine.

Answer (score 2):

*2016 answer for Riask 2.1.4 (earlier versions are different)*

Open the config file:

```
sudo vi /etc/riak/riak.conf +/http.internal
```

Change this line from:

```
listener.http.internal = 127.0.0.1:8098
```

to:

```
listener.http.internal = 0.0.0.0:8098
```

Then restart:

```
sudo riak restart
```

(Credits: https://gist.github.com/wavell/7979851)

This is really poorly documented in Riak 2.1.4, an instant point deduction in my evaluation.

Comment: Search term for Google: "riak enable external http"

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent ages on this until I found this answer.